# sorting mysql table by complex value

Tags: mysql, function

My table consists of records where every record has its own history which looks like this:

```
65465406540-245|65465408540-654
```

There is no limitation to history entries count (column type is text, so ...). And history entries are ALWAYS sorted from the oldest to the newest. Meaning the newest entry is on the right.

History entries are separated by pipe char "|". One history entry consists of timestamp, dash "-" as a separator and 1-4 digit number which represents user ID who made the change.

Now my problem is I'd like to sort records in my table by the most recent (or the oldest) history entry. How would I do that?

I was thinking about MySQL functions, since result has to come to my PHP script already sorted, but I don't know where to start, so every help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For oldest you can use RedFilters (now redacted) answer of

```
ORDER BY LEFT(column_name,11)
```

Ordering by newest is a bit more fun.

```
ORDER BY REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(column_name),1,LOCATE("|",REVERSE(column_name))-1))
```

Let's break this down.
We reverse the column and find the index of the first |

```
456-04580456456|542-04560456456
```

We then get the substring up to this point which gives us:

```
456-04580456456
```

This is the last item reversed so now we can simply `REVERSE` the string and order by that to order by the last item:

```
65465408540-654
```

This is pretty hideous however. I would consider doing this in PHP if at all possible.

Comment: I may have describe it wrong. What I need is sorting just by the last timestamp (asc/desc). And for that solved I'm truly grateful for @Jim complex query to which I just add ASC, or DESC. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked Jim's query, so it can also work with only one, and/or none history entry and is displaying only timestamp for easier date/time calculations.
Here it is:

```
SELECT *, 
    IF(
        LOCATE('|', history) > 0, 
        LEFT(
            REVERSE(
                LEFT(
                    REVERSE(history), 
                    LOCATE('|', REVERSE(history))-1
                )
            ), 
            10
        ), 
        LEFT(history, 10)
    ) AS last 
FROM table
ORDER BY last DESC
```